# Continuous domain vs continuous function?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

What is the difference between saying a function is continuous vs. discontinuous, vs. the domain being continuous or discontinuous?

Comment: A function is continuous on some interval $[a,b]$ or $(a,b)$ whenever $\lim \limits_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c) \; : x \in [a,b] \lor (a,b)$.  A domain is discontinuous whenever the interval of the domain contains a deleted neighborhood of some point in the domain.  I'm a math noob so if what I'm saying is incorrect and someone else corrects me I'll gladly delete this comment!

Comment: Generally, continuous domain may be referring to a _nonempty compact connected metric space_  as in topology. A continuous function is as the previous comment pointed out.